# getting error Cannot find module 'node-forge' while trying ng serve --open

Tags: angular, angular-cli

while creating first quick start app in angular5/cli. I faced the below mentioned error at Ubuntu 16.04. error : Cannot find module 'node-forge'
after some search for the error i used ng serve --port=5200. But didn't worked.
ng -v command's output is:
Angular CLI: 1.7.4

Node: 8.11.1

OS: linux x64

Angular:

Comment: when you did your npm install did you have any errors? for a quick workaround you can try to run a `npm i node-forge` to see if it comes down then try doing the `ng serve` again

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem and fixed by installing node-forge separately

`npm install node-forge@0.7.0`

i think angular is trying to install node-forge 0.7.5 and the folder is empty.